# Is it possible to call a function defined inside another function in Python?

Tags: python, function

For example:

```py
def foo():
    def bar():
        return

    # some code
    return

def foo2():
    # call bar() here?
```

Is it possible to put `bar()` inside `foo()` and call it in `foo2()`?

Comment: No, that's not possible. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Tomalak I want to expose some of the logic of `foo()` to other methods without refactoring out its code.

Comment: no it is not possible

Comment: If `foo` returns `bar`, then it could be passed to `foo2` and called there.  If `foo` has enough context used by `bar` to warrant this kind of thing, I think you should consider putting `foo` and `bar` in a class and sharing state (or code) that way.

Comment: In theory, you could dig into `foo.__code__.co_consts`, but in practice - don't.

Comment: *"expose some of the logic without refactoring"* - Refactor your code is all I can say.

Comment: "I want to expose some of the logic of foo() to other methods without refactoring out its code." And why don't you want to refactor out its code? That's... essentially what refactoring is *for*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is the first time I ask this, not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm just curious about it. But to give a reason, maybe it's for the same benefit of defining a method inside a method, to make it self contained and not fragmented(?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see what you mean, it seems search failed me. The fact that I couldn't find the duplicate suggests that other future searchers may benefit from my question and the discussion here.

Comment: Given that I got a bunch of hits from just sticking the title into Google, I don't think it suggests that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Most of my search hits are about trivial cases of calling method in class. Another reason may be because I searched method instead of function. So given a specific context and a considerable time, search can fail. Thanks for your efforts to link duplicates, it will help future searchers to jump to those duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat, you can do that - by declaring `bar` global:

```
def foo():
   global bar
   def bar():
      print("In bar")
```

But you cannot call `bar` unless you first call `foo`, because that's the function that defines `bar`:

```
bar()
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#NameError: name 'bar' is not defined    
foo()
bar()
#In bar
```

Overall, this is a very bad idea.

Comment: I agree it's a very bad idea. Looks like refactoring out the code is the way to go.

Comment: Not to mention what happens to any closure variables...

Comment: For futurers: closure variables are variables that `bar()` has access through `foo()`'s scope. This is a technique in functional programming to generate different functions (i.e., different `bar()`) with different "states", similarly to private variables in OOP.